# How to assert on error message in nodeunit?

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I am trying to write assertions that check error messages in nodeunit. I want the test to fail if the error message doesn't match what I expect.  However, it does not seem like the API exists for this.  Here is what I am trying to do:

foo.js

```
function foo() {
  ...
  throw new MyError('Some complex message');
}
```

foo.test.js

```
testFoo(test) {
  test.throws(foo, MyError, 'Some complex message');
}
```

I would like `testFoo` to fail if the error message is *not* 'Some complex message', but that's not how it works. It seems like 'Some complex message' is just a message that explains the test failure. It is not involved with the assertion.  What is the best way to do this in nodeunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method of [nodeunit API](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit#api-documentation)

```
throws(block, [error], [message]) - Expects block to throw an error.
```

can accept a function for the [error] parameter.
The function take the `actual` argument and returns `true|false` to indicate the success or a failure of the assertion.

In this way, if you wish to assert that some method throws an `Error` and that error contains some specific message, you should write a test like this:

```
  test.throws(foo, function(err) {
    return (err instanceof Error) && /message to validate/.test(err)
  }, 'assertion message');
```

Example:

```
function MyError(msg) {
  this.message = msg;
}
MyError.prototype = Error.prototype;

function foo() {
  throw new MyError('message to validate');
}

exports.testFooOk = function(test) {
  test.throws(foo, function(actual) { 
    return (actual instanceof MyError) && /message to validate/.test(actual) 
  }, 'Assertion message');
  test.done();
};

exports.testFooFail = function(test) {
  test.throws(foo, function(actual) { 
    return (actual instanceof MyError) && /another message/.test(actual) 
  }, 'Assertion message');
  test.done();
};
```

Output:

```
✔ testFooOk
✖ testFooFail
```

Actually any testing framework that implements functions from node.js assert module, support that. For example: [node.js assert](https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.3.0/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message) or [Should.js](http://shouldjs.github.io/#should-throws)

Comment: Thanks. This is not mentioned in the nodeunit api. After inspecting the code, I also see that `[error]` could be a regex. This regex is applied to the error's message. A match indicates success. But your proposal is better since it allows me to check for both at once.